# How to put a password on the database on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I want to set a password to a database on a PostgreSQL server, is it possible? any idea.

without using ROLE.

1. When connected with a role, only the Select operation should be performed in the database.
2. The database must have its own password.
3. Even if there is a SUPER USER who does not know the password of the database, she should not
   connect to the database.

3rd most important step.

Comment: Did you check the manual? It's all there: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html

Comment: A database cannot have it's own password. A connection has to come from a user(role). If you want to restrict access to the database you need to use [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).